# EJBTimerService stop working

Tags: ejb-timer

I have a question about EJBTimerService.

EJBTimerService is central controller, which the use java.util.Timer.

```
java.util.Timer jdkTimer = ejbContainerUtil.getTimer();
jdkTimer.schedule(timerTask, timerExpiration);
```

**My problem is  java.util.Timer.mainLoop stop working and new task not scheduled.**

After GlassFish source code analyzing I made conclusions.
Problem happens because we receive RejectedExecutionException from ejbContainerUtil.addWork(work) when EJBTimeout.

```
EJBTimerTask timerTask = new EJBTimerTask(timerExpiration, timerId, this);
timerService_.taskExpired(timerId_);
```

Inside ejbContainerUtil.addWork we have defaultThreadPoolExecutor.submit()

```
defaultThreadPoolExecutor = EjbThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor + AbortPolicy.

TaskExpiredWork work = new TaskExpiredWork(this, timerId);
ejbContainerUtil.addWork(work);
```

So timer java.util.Timer.mainLoop stop working,
because core poll is exceeded, queue is full, max core is exceeded, then we receive from ThreadPoolExecutor RejectedExecutionException.

**I'm corret? Or I'm wrong?**